# How do I use the keyword "var" when declaring local variables?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was searching the net for a way of declaring local variables and came across this Oracle [page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/local-variable-type-inference.html). The page talks about using the keyword "var".

I am using IntelliJ and I believe I correctly setup my project to use "var" but it's not working properly. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

In the project language level, I also tried 10 but no difference.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set your Project Bytecode Version to 11 in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler ?

Comment: Check the language level setting, under "Project Settings -> Modules" and the "Sources" tab (right side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more place that could be not turn on an appropriate feature

Please check *Project bytecode version*. It is placed on File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler

[image: Project bytecode version]